# Why do I have Timber logger 500 HTTP error when logging?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, timber

I just upgraded my Elixir/Phoenix for my application to Elixir 1.9.0, Phoenix 1.4.10.

The Timber logger backend stopped working after the upgrade. I always got 500 HTTP error when logging to Timber.

My new timber package version is 3.1.0.
The old one (Timber 2.8.0 on Elixir 1.6+, Phoenix 1.3+) worked fine.

I tried the doc here: https://docs.timber.io/setup/protocols/http

It turned out that both the POST and the curl examples in that section returned 500 error too.

Anybody got the same problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The URL in the examples is https://logs.timber.io/sources/YOUR_SOURCE_ID/frames

When I created a Source in Timber, it had a name.
I used the source name in Timber instead of the source id to replace "YOUR_SOURCE_ID", so Timber returned a 500.

It was terrible, because at the very least, it should have returned a 422, to indicate that the request format was ok, but it could not process for some reason.

Anyway, there were 2 cases where Timber returned 500 incorrectly:

1. JSON data in the body has bad format. Should have returned 400. (Might be fixed now - not sure).
2. The source_id in the URL is wrong. Should have returned 422. Still error.